# SQL:How use analytic function on multiple columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to statistics multiple columns,the following is my writing:

```
with 
  t_suml1 as(select id, date, sum(list1) result from table group by id,date),
  t_avgl2 as(select id, date, avg(list2) result from talbe group by id,date),
  t_countl3 as(select id, date, count(list3) result from table group by id,date)
select s.id, s.date, s.result, t_avgl2.result, t_countl3.result
  from t_suml1 s
  inner join t_avgl2 a on s.id=a.id and s.date=a.date
  inner join t_countl3 c on s.id=c.id and s.date=c.date
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: why not use select id, date,sum(list1),avg(list2), count(list3) result from table group by id,date? you have 3 different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, date,sum(list1),avg(list2), count(list3) result from table group by id,date
```

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

```
select s.id, s.date, s.result, t_avgl2.result
   ,sum(list1) over (partition by id, date)
   ,avg(list1) over (partition by id, date) 
   ,count(list1) over (partition by id, date) 
--totals:
   ,sum(list1) over () as total_sum
   ,avg(list1) over ()  as total_avg
   ,count(list1) over () as total_cnt 
  from t_suml1 s
  inner join t_avgl2 a on s.id=a.id and s.date=a.date
  inner join t_countl3 c on s.id=c.id and s.date=c.date
```